# multidimensional array keys reasign

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm struggling on a multidimensional arrays ... 
I have merged to arrays and I should assign to them a new value  which should be used as a key:

```
$content = array();
$content[0]['text'] = 'xxxxx';
$content[0]['order']=1

$content[1]['text'] = 'yyyy';
$content[1]['order']=3

$content[2]['text'] = 'yyyyddd';
$content[2]['order']=2
```

I need to reorder this array by content['order'] values and I'm struggling here.

Please, I'd really need a help here .

Comment: So you want to order the top-level array so that it respects the ['order'] key of the children? Which way do you want to sort? What have you tried

Comment: I tried to reasign keys in array - I did it before many times, but today all not working :( I just need to display them from lower to higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function sort_orders($a, $b) {
    if($a['order'] == $b['order']) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['order'] < $b['order']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($content, "sort_orders");
```

Comment: Thank you for quick help ... I had to combine two different tables and it turned out all so complicated that at the end I couldn't find solution for this task - I tried similar soloution before, with no effect

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [usort()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and a compare function, like so:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['order'] == $b['order']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['order'] < $b['order']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($content, 'cmp');
```